# Sobolev Space with partial inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In my work, I encountered the following problem.

Consider the set of real-valued functions, which are ``balanced'', that is the set of bounded functions $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)=\pm\lambda$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. That is, bounded functions whose limits at $x=\pm \infty$ exist and are additive opposite. I would like to make this a Hilbert space. The inner product cannot involve the function themselves but, if I assume the existence of first derivatives (in some sense), I would like to define my inner product to be $$(f,g)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'g' dx.$$ Is there a way to restrict the functions (infinitely differentiable for example) so that we have a Hilbert space?

If you want to solve a related but simpler problem and forego the balance part, consider functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is there a way to restrict the functions (that is consider a subset of $H^1$) such that this subset of $H^1$ endowed with the inner product above is a Hilbert space.

In a nutshell, because my inner product cannot involve the functions themselves (because the functions do not converge to zero at $\infty$), I would like my inner product to involve the derivatives only.

Comment: You'll need to somehow "mod out constants" so that $\int f'^2 dx = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$.

Comment: So for instance, $H^1$ mod constants, i.e. identifying functions which differ only by a constants as the same, can be given that inner product, in which case it is a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Ian: The only constant function in $H^1$ is zero, so strictly speaking, you don't need to identify anything there.

Comment: @PhoemueX Good point; sometimes I get stuck in "bounded domain mode". Unfortunately that means that $H^1$ itself does not help here. Perhaps you can instead say: start with $L^1 \cap L^2$, define antiderivatives of those functions, mod out constants, define the inner product as above, and then extend by density if necessary?